# MySQL - GROUP BY, select only the first row when grouping

Tags: mysql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I'm having a problem with grouping specific columns into one. When I use GROUP BY, the last row always gets selected when it should be the first row.

**The main query is:**

```
SELECT cpme_id, 
       medicine_main_tbl.med_id, 
       Concat(med_name, ' (', med_dosage, ') ', med_type) AS Medicine, 
       med_purpose, 
       med_quantity, 
       med_expiredate 
FROM   medicine_main_tbl 
       JOIN medicine_inventory_tbl 
         ON medicine_main_tbl.med_id = medicine_inventory_tbl.med_id 
WHERE  Coalesce(med_quantity, 0) != 0 
       AND Abs(Datediff(med_expiredate, Now())) 
ORDER  BY med_expiredate;
```

[SELECT without GROUP BY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPoGk.png)

If I `GROUP BY` using any duplicate column value (in this case, I used med_id):

[SELECT with GROUP BY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUQNM.png)

I'm trying to get this output

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yln65.png)

The output should only be the first two from the first query. Obviously, I cannot use LIMIT.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: The expected output should be the first two rows in the first query.

Comment: If your version is 'old', see the tag I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using MariaDB, I recommend using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY med_id ORDER BY med_expireDate) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT cpme_id, med_id, Medicine, med_purpose, med_quantity, med_expireDate
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This assumes that the "first" row for a given medicine is the one having the earliest expire date.  This was the only interpretation of your data which agreed with the expected output.

Comment: I think `rank()` would give the desired result if the requirement is to fetch the first row from the grouped data instead of `row_number`?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal No, `RANK` (or `DENSE_RANK`) would return more than one record should there be ties for first place.  `ROW_NUMBER` only would return a single record, always.  It's up the OP as to what he wants here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you very much!